# How do I custom theme for my MUI data grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI Datagrid, which I am using.  I want to apply some stylesheet to it which will be used across all places for data grid.

So I tried

```
  components: {
    root: {
         "& .MuiDataGrid-cell": {
           fontSize: "18px",
          textOverflow: "ellipsis",
           whiteSpace: "pre",
         },
    },
  },
```

But it's not getting applied.
I want to apply to the Columns of MUI should have a border bottom. But this is not applying.

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `styled` feature that provided by MUI itself. Follow like this

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const GridContainer = styled('div')`
  .MuiDataGrid-cell {
    font-size: 18px !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    white-space: pre !important;
  }
`;
```

Then use `<GridContainer> ... </GridContainer>`

Answer (score 0):

i share you my custome theme
at first create a new js file name Design.js or everything you want and past this code:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const InfoThemes = createTheme({
components: {
   MuiDataGrid: {
     styleOverrides: {
       root: {
         minHeight: 500,
         '& .MuiDataGrid-row':{
          // color: '#232D3F'
         },
         '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle':{
          fontSize: "15px"
         },
         '& .MuiDataGrid-selectedRowCount':{
          color: 'white'
         },
         '& .MuiCheckbox-root':{
          color: '#9504b5'
         }
       },
       columnHeader: {
         backgroundColor: '#9504b5',
         '& .MuiSvgIcon-root':{
          color:'white'
         }
       },
       columnHeaderTitle: {
        color: 'white',
      },
      columnHeaderSortIcon: {
        color: 'white',
      },
      footerContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#9504b5',
      },
     },
   },
   MuiFormControl:{
    styleOverrides:{
      root:{
        '& .MuiSvgIcon-root':{
          color:'#9504b5'
        }
      }
    }
   },
   MuiTablePagination:{
    styleOverrides:{
      toolbar:{
        color: "white",
        '& .MuiButtonBase-root':{
          color: "white"
        }
      },
      selectIcon:{
        color:"white"
      },
      root:{
        '& .MuiSvgIcon-colorPrimary': {
          color: 'white'
          },
        
      }
    }
   },
   MuiIconButton:{
    styleOverrides:{
      root:{
        color:'white',
        '& .MuiSvgIcon-root':{
          color: 'white'
        }
      },
    }
   },
},
```

});

now on your Data grid import your theme like this:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { InfoThemes } from "../Design";

<ThemeProvider theme={InfoThemes}>
 <DataGrid        
   your data row column here ....
  />
</ThemeProvider>
```

if you dont like the color or something else you can change it on InfoTheme or create and export an other theme with a different modification that you want (celll, column, header .....).
for more documentation go there:
[Data grid](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#DataGrid-css-selectedRowCount)
i hope i've helped you